# How to populate Author reference from new Comment Object in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have this Post Request in `CommentController.java`:

```
@PostMapping("path=/comments")
public void saveComment(@RequestBody Map<String, String> requestBody) {
    this.commentService.saveComment(
            Comment.builder()
            .content(requestBody.get("content"))
            .author()       // need to get the user id somehow for the request body
                            // probably from the user's session?
            .post()
            .build());
}
```

But am wondering the best way to attach the author to this comment. Would the author id get passed in through the Request Body somehow (somehow through the user's session on the frontend) or is there a better way to do this? If Author id was passed in through the Request Body, i could do make another database call to get the author with that id such as:

```
...
.author(this.authorService.getAuthorById(requestBody.get("authorId"))
.post(...)
.build();
```

The author and post are foreign keys to respective rows in Author and Post tables.

Comment: It really depends on the use case that you want to achieve. Adding authorId in request body is also means that everyone call your api is responsible to decide which comment belongs to which author (do you accept it in some edge case like some malicious client/user freely posting a comment and then assigning the author to someone else?). On another hand, getting user id from current request scope would strict your API to apply the logic only for current user.

Comment: In case you want to get current user_id in your current request, you might need to post your current configuration of spring security (or any other mechanism that you are using)

Comment: @HưngChu Your second comment is what i'm trying to do where the Post request will be from the current user. I'm new to Spring/SpringBoot, do you have some resources to look at to for something like this?

Comment: if you want to learn, then there are a lot of resources on internet with keyword "spring boot security example". Form login could be a good start: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

Comment: How are you sending this Post, is it directly from something like a form or are you building a POST request using ajax?

Comment: @DavidKariuki Eventually from a form, but haven't got that set up yet.